# How can I list objects in a S3 bucket from the browser, without setting up CORS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Using the JS SDK configured with a valid API key and secret, I can list the content of a S3 bucket when running the code on the server.

However, the same code (with the same credentials) does not run in the browser because of CORS. (S3 requires CORS to be enabled on the bucket)

Why can I do anything on AWS in the browser via the SDK (create SQS queues, databases, etc.), but specifically S3 has CORS restriction?

I don't understand this restriction, am I doing something wrong?

**Note: I am using administrator access API keys in the browser, this is an internal admin panel, not a public application.**

**Note 2: I know this isn't the usual use case, this is not a public app. Also I do not want to use a proxy server to bypass CORS.**

Comment: Because CORS is a security mechanism built for code running in browsers. This is different from managing your resources in the AWS web console.

Comment: I know, but the whole AWS API does not enforce CORS, yet specifically some S3 endpoints do.

I can do anything on the AWS API **from the browser** without CORS issue, except for some S3 endpoints. That's weird, is there anything I can do around that? Am I using the wrong API?

Comment: If you open the network tab when you upload a file to S3 via the web console, the browser also generates a preflight request. There is no way to bypass this unless you use a proxy.

Comment: Thanks, this is really weird that this API behaves so differently. Thanks for confirming though.